# Value not overriding while set its value in loop in Vue JS and Firebase

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-component

I am getting data from firebase and overriding my `roomName` value in the loop. But outside the loop, it will not get the updated value.
Can someone please help me with the same?

```js
export default {
    name: "Chat",
    components: {
        ChatMessages
    },
    data(){
        return{
            rooms: [],
            roomName: null,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getRooms();
    },
    methods: {
        getRooms() {
            roomsRef.orderByChild('name').once('value').then(snapshot => {
                this.rooms = snapshot.val();
            });
        },
        selectUser: function(userId) {
            $.each(this.rooms,function(index,data){
                if((data.sender_id == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid && data.receiver_id == userId ) || (data.sender_id == userId && data.receiver_id == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid )){
                    this.roomName = data.room_name;
                }
            });
                  
            if(this.roomName == null){
                console.log("Null");
                console.log(this.roomName);
            }else{
                console.log("Not Null");
                console.log(this.roomName);
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: To use `this` inside another function you have to use arrow function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. So it should be `$.each(this.rooms, (index, data) => {`.

Comment: @User 28, It's working. Thanks my today's Hero. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by User 28 in the comment section, you need to use an arrow function:

```
        $.each(this.rooms,(index,data) => {
            if((data.sender_id == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid && data.receiver_id == userId ) || (data.sender_id == userId && data.receiver_id == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid )){
                this.roomName = data.room_name;
            }
        });
```

Explanation. A "normal" `function` binds its own `this`. An arrow `function` inherits the `this` of the parent scope. Read more here: https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc